# AutoUnattend.xml Windows 8 setup

Tags: windows, windows-8, xml, windows-installation, unattended

I need a example of how to make an **Autounattend.xml** for the Windows 8 x64 Core ISO setup.

I saw a example from MSDN but don't helped me in nothing, my unattended always fails (is not recognized by the setup).

This are the values I want to specify in the custom installation:

```
key = xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
Version to install = Windows 8 (CORE)
Timezone = París/Madrid/Spain (Romance Standard Time)
Drive to install: (Default, I mean to don't force this)
StartScreenColor = Black+blue (The third color in the palette)
PC-NAME = Elektro-PC
Use local account = Yes
Username = Administrator
Password = (NOTHING)
```

...But I don't know if I can specify all of that.

Someone can do this xml for me or helping me to do it by myself?

This is the last xml I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Created by Win Toolkit v1.4.1.22-->
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>FB4WR-32NVD-4RW79-XQFWH-CYQG3</Key>
                <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>FB4WR-32NVD-4RW79-XQFWH-CYQG3</Key>
                <WillShowUI>Always</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ProductKey>FB4WR-32NVD-4RW79-XQFWH-CYQG3</ProductKey>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ProductKey>FB4WR-32NVD-4RW79-XQFWH-CYQG3</ProductKey>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>mars-one</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                <Value>mars-one</Value>
                <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>9999999</LogonCount>
                <Username>Administrator</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>mars-one</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                <Value>mars-one</Value>
                <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>9999999</LogonCount>
                <Username>Administrator</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, wow. Don't try to write the XML file yourself. If you read through some of the deployment documentation you'll see that is *not* recommended. (I'm not holding that against you. The Microsoft deployment documentation is absolutely mind numbing.)

Use [Windows System Image Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825087.aspx) instead. It's a very nice GUI for building unattended XML files. It will also lay out all the options you can set, so you don't need to guess.

It's part of the [Windows ADK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh825420.aspx), which you can [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very usefull information, then is a "capture tool" to capture the Win8 installation values I set?, but can you specify the basic steps of how to do it?, I'm on Windows 7 and Windows 8 is installed in a VirtualMachine, I have the ISO of Win8 unmounted in the Win7 installation of course, I'm downloading the entire Windows ADK package but appears to be a windows kit so a lot of tools... how I start to do what say?

Comment: I found a tutorial, no matter

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/599456/windows-system-image-manager-cant-validate-my-asnwer  here you can help me a little more