# Windows System Image Manager can't validate my answer

Tags: windows-8, unattended, waik

### Problem

When I do my modifications and I apply to "**validate answer**" I get a lot of errors

In the picture you can see the WSIM version I'm using (6.2.9200),

...The errors in the picture are saying this more or less :

```
"The configuration was not modified. The response file don't will be saved"

"The configuration "XXXXX" is obsolete in the Windows Image"
```

...And the image I'm touching is a Windows 8 x64 Core (...\Source\install.wim)

I've followed the steps [here](http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/575-what-is-windows-sim-and-how-can-i-use-it/).

I don't know if maybe I'm using the wrong version of the WSIM.

[image]

But this is what I've expected:

(No warnings or errors)

[image]

---

### question

What is causing the errors?.

Comment: This is an old question that's already been answered.  Just a suggestion: the question would benefit from some context.  What "answer" are you referring to in the title?  1st sentence: what "modifications", and "validate" what answer?  Maybe people familiar with that utility can figure out what you're referring to (and they're the ones who can answer).  However, suppose somebody else has the same problem.  If the wording isn't generally understandable, it won't help them to find the question or answer in a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSIM checks the settings in the image when it builds the catalog file, and it is telling you that your settings in the answer file are no different that what is already in the image. The Catalog files section of the TechNet article '[Understanding Windows Image Files and Catalog Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744249(v=ws.10).aspx)' explains the catalog files in more detail.

Additionally, please refer to the TechNet article '[Changed Answer File Settings From Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825617.aspx) for reference with the errors about The Configuration 'XXXXX' is Obsolete' messages. You didn't post the answer file here, so we can't go through it to find exactly which ones are obsolete or deprecated. You should be able to find them all in the article or in the '[Unattended Windows Setup Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699026.aspx)'.

Hope this helps,